# Why do I need to cast a Float to float before cast to byte?

Tags: java, casting

```
Float f = new Float(10.71);    
byte b = (byte)f;
```

I get

```
Cannot cast from Float to byte
```

Why do I have to do this?

```
byte b = (byte)(float)f;
```

Comment: you are casting `Float` to `float` not `float` to `float`, subtle difference.

Comment: The only thing that is subtle about the difference is the superficial syntax. BTW neither `Float`->`float` nor `float`->`byte` are actually casts: first is unboxing, second is narrowing conversion.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia yea. I edited that because the title was misleading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot cast an `Object` to a primitive. You can only cast `Float` to `float` because of java's autoboxing feature.

This "feature" is being assaulted endlessly by angry developers but I guess it is here to stay for backwards compatibility reasons.

I don't like it either but you have to learn to live with it. Just don't use `Long`s or `Float`s if you can because it is not funny when you try to do computation with `null` values.

Comment: True enough.  I'd also add that unless you need the wrapper, just use primitives.

Comment: @MadConan Indeed. Tough marginal, I'd spare Java the task of auto/unboxing when it's not required.

Answer (score 4):

Since `Float` is a "boxed" `float`, you cannot cast it directly. However, in your situation you do not need casting at all - [you can go directly to `byte`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#byteValue%28%29), like this:

```
byte b0 = f1.byteValue();
```

The above is possible because `Float` is a subclass of [`java.lang.Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html), which provides the `byteValue()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware on the differences between classes and primitives.

You'll never be allowed to cast any object to a primitive. These are different entities as an object creation pass through an instantiation, hence JVM treat objects and primitives as different entities without relation between them.

The classes related to primitives (Integer, Float, ...) are used to wrap these primitives and provide some manipulation methods. Furthermore, this classes have a specific cast procedure that allows then to return the primitive they are wrapping.

Only for these objects

```
float myFloat = (float)f;
```

is equivalent to

```
float myFloat = f.floatValue();
```

Once you have your object transformed to a float type, you can cast it backwards to an int (which will remove the decimal digits obviously).

```
int myInt = (int)(float)f;
int mySameInt = (int)f.floatValue();     //same value than above
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an Object to a primitive.

However, you can use the `byteValue()` method from `Number` class.

Comment: You can use the "cast operator" to unbox a `Float` into `float`. The thing you can't do is at once unbox and convert.

Comment: That's not a cast, Marko. An unboxing action is performed, not a cast.

Comment: There is no casting whatsoever involved in either this question or your answer. So, either the statement "you cannot cast an Object to a primitive" is irrelevant because you can't cast a `float` to a `byte`, either, or, if we accept the looser meaning, is incorrect because you *can* apply the "cast" operator to `Float` and get a `float`.

Comment: He got no such thing; he got a compiler error, and the error message uses the term "cast" in the looser sense (most probably, because in the strict sense the statement is also correct).

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely certain but can't you do

```
byte bo = f1.byteValue();
```